# Is this operator related to the resolvent formalism (aka Green function)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

I am working in the area of graph theory, where the matrix $L$ is the combinatorial matrix of a graph, a positive semidefinite matrix.

The resolvent of a matrix $L$ (improperly called Green function) is defined as:

$$R(z)=(zI - L)^{-1}$$

In my calculations, related to a problem on graphs, I need to make sense of an expression that seems related to the resolvent, but with opposite sign.
In particular the quantity that I am trying to make sense of is the following:

$$F(z)=\mathrm{Tr}\left \lbrack z(zI+L)^{-1} \right \rbrack$$

where $\mathrm{Tr}$ is the trace of a matrix. This quantity seems related in some way to the resolvent, but I see a positive sign in front of $L$, and the factor $z$ looks like computing the first momentum of a spectral density.

Is this possible to put the quantity $F$ in relation to the resolvent $R$? This would greatly help me to understand a lot of things.

Comment: $F(-z)/z= tr R(z)$

Comment: Many thanks, that was easy indeed. Apart from this manipulation, I am thinking how I can I say more about $F(z)$. Is this related to the moments of the trace of $L$?

Comment: What do you mean for moments of the trace of $L$?

Comment: I am considering expectation over random matrix ensembles. If I identify the Stieltjes transform $s(L)=\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{Tr}\lbrack (zI - L)^{-1}\rbrack$ and expand it in series, I get that $s(z)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}}\mathrm{Tr}[ L^k ]$, thus it can be seen as the moment generating function of $L$. For this reason I think that my $F(z)$ should be related in some way to the moments of $L$. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, the moments are defined as positive powers, at least in measure theory. Here instead it seems to me that the moments uses negative powers.  However, $F(z)  =n zs(-z)$, so that $F$ determins the same moments as $s$ except for the sign and the order (they are rescaled: $z^k$ instead of $z^{k+1}$). But I do not know if this is the type of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this maths question?